# XAMPP Apache works, but not on portable version

Tags: sql, apache, xampp

So since the title is a bit vague.
Bassicly I have XAMPP installed latest version. I am able to run the apache on there. However when I try it on a portable version which I need for an application. It doesn't work. both in the same environment and with the same processes running. I tried changing the port in the httpd.conf file with no result. I closed skype so it's not that. otherwise the latest version wouldn't work either. Is there anything else i could try?

Answer (score 0):

So i hope i can help someone today, it turns out you are not allowed to use brackets inside the folder you are running XAMPP from. it was a really hard thing to spot for someone with not much XAMPP expirience.

short answer: Don't use brackets in folder names related to XAMPP.